# Not able to create Win32 console application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010-express

I try to create a new project, I click, I chose a name, and when a dialog box opens with:

```
a.finish
b.cancel
```

Buttons, it doesn't let me click, below on the bottom of the IDE I can see "creating project" but I can't click on anything but close, when I close, there's no project, because I could click "finish". What's wrong with my IDE?

I use Visual C++ Express Edition 2010.

I've been able to create projects before, I tried restarting, re-installing, it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2d99af00-b3f8-45fd-9c86-04d0ea7de264/cannot-create-win32-console-application

Have a great day!

Comment: ie. you reinstall/use visual studio instead 2010