# Why can't I create a new win32 console visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I'm running visual studio 2013 professional on windows 8
Now, every time I try to start a new project solution in C++ win32 application, the idle-cursor turns to wait-cursor, nothing seems to happen for a long time, the minute i hit the screen, windows tells me visual studio isn't responding, then I'm forced to kill visual studio.

It keeps crashing

I tried searching for answers, found one about [not able to create a win32 console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595389/not-able-to-create-win32-console-application) had a resolution, tried it but I get access denied.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0>devenv /setup

Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Version 12.0.30723.0.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

The operation could not be completed. Access is denied.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0>
```

**After first feedback**

I rebooted, retried using the visual studio command prompt, while running it as an administrator. This time it didn't complain, nor outputted anything.

I also tried running visual studio itself as an administrator, but still get same the effect when attempting to create a new c++ win32 console project.

**After more searching**

[Based on this reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c5aaa761-1a73-440e-bf72-ce70047169d6/help-visual-studio-hangs-creating-new-projects?forum=vssetup)
I tried

1. `devenv /Resetsettings`  ...  didn't resolve it
2. `devenv /ResetSkipPkgs`  ...  didn't resolve it
3. `devenv /Safemode`       ...  resolved it, but not sure if it's ideal

Comment: some code would be helpful.

Comment: @someone_smiley there is no code... I'm just trying to open a new project that's c++ win32 console based

Comment: Restart the computer.  Then run your CMD prompt with administrator privileges and try that solution again.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware I ran as an administrator, then after running same command, it didn't complain nor output anything.

Comment: this can be anything.  all it means is that visual studio is waiting on something.  last time this happened to me, it's because visual studio was trying to load something (recent file list, etc.) from a network resource that is not online.  another time this happened to me, it was because the hard drive was starting to fail and visual studio waiting on some data files.  i am sure i can think of a dozen other reason why this can happen...

Comment: @thang, well it apparently works in Safemode (updated my question)

Comment: that means you installed a 3rd party plugin that hangs/crash visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current resolution is to create a project in safe mode

**Procedure**

1. Run visual studio command prompt
2. Type in: `devenv /Safemode`
3. Create a new project

The project should now be accessible by going through the standard way of opening visual studio

**Update**

I uninstalled visual studio, then reinstalled. Unfortunately, I still can't run visual studio normally just to create a project, it continues to hang indefinitely every time I do. The procedure above is still the only resolution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you run this on Windows 8 ?
In win8, folder "program files" are not allowed to write except for adminstrators

Comment: Yes =/, also I ran as an administrator, then after running same command, it didn't complain nor output anything.

Comment: VS 2013 is UAC aware and doesn't try to create your project under "program files"